# Exporting recaptcha key to mobile application

Tags: recaptcha, google-admin-sdk, google-people-api

I am exporting all the data from my website to a mobile application. So, is there a way that I could use the same recaptcha keys for my mobile application that I am already using on my site?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are migrating your website data from a public internet server to a mobile app, and you may consider keeping the same [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) keys in the migration. If that is the case, I strongly advise against it. You can easily [create a new key pair](https://g.co/recaptcha/v3) and implement it in the mobile app. If there is any issue that prevents you from creating a new key pair, please don't hesitate to share the scenario details.